# Writing data to json in python

Tags: python, json, numpy, dictionary

I have np array of 3*10 dimension, each column is vertex with its x, y, z co-ordinate.

I want to output this data to JSON file like following.

```
{
"v0" : {
"x" : 0.0184074,
"y" : 0.354329,
"z" : -0.024123
},
"v1" : {
"x" : 0.34662,
"y" : 0.338337,
"z" : -0.0333459
}
#and so on...
```

Here is my python code

```
#vertices is np array of 3*10 dimention
for x in xrange(0,10):
s += "\n\"v\""+ str(x) +" : {";
s += "\n\"x\" : "+str(vertices[0][x]) +","
s += "\n\"y\" : "+str(vertices[1][x]) +","
s += "\n\"z\" : "+str(vertices[2][x]) 
s += "\n},"
s += "\n}"


with open("text.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(s, outfile, indent=4)
r = json.load(open('text.json', 'r')) #this line updated, fixed wrong syntax
```

It gives following error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read.py", line 32, in <module>
    r = json.loads("text.json");
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Further when I open saved json file in chrome it looks ugly like this,

```
"{\n\"v\"0 : {\n\"x\" : 0.0184074,\n\"y\" : 0.354329,\n\"z\" : -0.024123\n}" #and so on ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: don't fix your code on the go, it will confuse anyone how looks at the question in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is raised because you use `json.loads`, which expects a JSON string as argument not a filename.

However, the way you dump the JSON is wrong too. You are building a string `s`, which contains invalid JSON. Then, you are dumping this single string with `json.dump`.

Instead of building a string, build a dictionary:

```
data = {}
for x in xrange(0,10):
    data["v" + str(x)] = {
        "x": str(vertices[0][x]),
        "y": str(vertices[1][x]),
        "z": str(vertices[2][x]), 
}
```

Dump that dictionary as JSON to a file:

```
with open("text.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)
```

Use `json.load` with a file object as argument, instead of `json.loads` with the filename.

```
with open('text.json', 'r') as infile:
    r = json.load(infile)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `json.load(fileObj)`, here I have modified:

```
#vertices is np array of 3*10 dimention
for x in xrange(0,10):
    s += "\n\"v\""+ str(x) +" : {";
    s += "\n\"x\" : "+str(vertices[0][x]) +","
    s += "\n\"y\" : "+str(vertices[1][x]) +","
    s += "\n\"z\" : "+str(vertices[2][x]) 
    s += "\n},"
    s += "\n}"


with open("text.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(s, outfile, indent=4)
r = json.load(open('text.json', 'r'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct your json properly first:

```
s = {}
for x in xrange(0,10):
    s["v"+str(x)]= { "x":str(vertices[0][x]),"y":str(vertices[1][x]),"z":str(vertices[2][x]) }
```

Then you dump it:

```
with open("text.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(s, outfile, indent=4)
```